# Playing two videos of different resolutions simultaneously in android ?

Tags: android, android-video-player

I am working on app in which i need to compare two video simultaneously.

I tried using two surface views but it doesn't work.The problem facing is when two videos are of different resolutions, both doesn't play simultaneously..

Comment: Plz help me to solve this problem,